# My Ajax output is disappearing after one sec

Tags: php, ajax, forms, ajaxform

I am using Ajax with form in Ajax I have used a if condition for validation if my form is empty it should display a message that all fields are required and if fields are fill it should add data in dB and display a success message although everything is working perfectly except one thing which is that my output only display for a second and then automatically disappears can anyone help me in this regard:

`

```
<html>
<head>
  <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html;charset=UTF-8">
  <title>Document</title>
  <script src="jquery.js"></script>
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="stylesheet.css">
</head>
<body>
  <h1>PHP & Ajax Seralize Form</h1>
  <form id="form-data" method="post">
      Name<br><input type="text" name="name" id="name" value=""><br><br>
      Age<br><input type="number" name="number" id="age" value=""><br><br>
      Gender<br>
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male
        <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Fe-male<br><br>

      <select name="country">
        <option value="Kashmir">Kashmir</option>
        <option value="Egypt">Egypt</option>
        <option value="Norway">Norway</option>
        <option value="Iceland">Iceland</option>
      </select><br>
      <br><input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
  </form>

<div id="response">

</div>

<script>
  $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#submit').click(function(){
        var name = $('#name').val();
        var age = $('#age').val();

        if( name== "" || age== ""){
          $('#response').fadeIn();
          $('#response').removeClass('success-msg').addClass('error-msg').html("All fields are required");
        }else{
          $.ajax({
          url: 'save-form.php',
          type: 'POST',
          data: $('#form-data').serialize(),
          success: function(result){
            $('#response').fadeIn();
            $('#response').removeClass('error-msg').addClass('success-msg').html(result);
          }
        });
    }
  });
});
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

probably your page is refreshed, try to use preventDefault to prevent the refresh

```
$('#submit').click(function(event){
        //your code here
      event.preventDefault();
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You have a button with type `"submit"`.

```html
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Save">
```

As the click-event occurs on this button, your form will be send to the server. You have no action attribute defined on your form, so it redirects after submit to the same URL.

As [Sterko](https://stackoverflow.com/users/13474687/sterko) stated, you could use a event-handler to prevent the submission of your form due to the submit button.